# Calling <img src > tag in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display all images in a array on my web page. Can I call img tag in a loop? Or if anyone could suggest a way to print all images with source urls in a array will be very helpful?

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
function myFunction() {
    var index;
    var urls = ["Banana.jpg", "Orange.jpg", "Apple.png", "Mango.jpg"];

    for (index = 0; index < urls.length; index++) {
         var newImage = '<img src="+url[index]+" alt="#" /> ' + index;
         container.innerHTML += newImage;
     }

}
</script>
```

PS: I'm newbie in JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't use the `innerHTML += method`. Use the [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method instead.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var urls = ["Banana.jpg", "Orange.jpg", "Apple.png", "Mango.jpg"];
for( i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="'+urls[i]+'">');
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**PS**, if you are going to wrap this code inside a function. Remember to call the function.

Comment: I am running the webpage and getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null" on the console..any suggestions?

Comment: There is something wrong with the string you are passing to the method. I can't help much without being able to reproduce the error myself. You would need to provide me with updated code.

Comment: <div id="chart_id" class="chart" ></div>
<script>
 var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
 var urls = ["http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CUQGGYGWIAA2eJp.jpg",          "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CUQGGYGWIAA2eJp.jpg"];
 for( i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
   container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="'+urls[i]+'">');
 }

 
</script>

Comment: sorry for the comment..solved the issue
thanx anyways )

Comment: The syntax for the array you built is incorrect. Separate the url strings with just a comma, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your syntax for building the img tags are wrong, notice below that the array isn't par of the string literal but concatenated to it.

```
'<img src="'+url[index]+'" alt="#" /> '
```

Also I would build the html first, then add it to the div.

```
var newImages = '';
for (index = 0; index < urls.length; index++) {
     newImages += '<img src="'+url[index]+'" alt="#" /> ' + index;
 }
 container.innerHTML += newImages;
```